# Homeomorphic subsets of rationals

Tags: general-topology

The set of rationals in $[0,1]$ is homeomorphic to the set of rationals in $(0,1)$ by a result of Sierpiński. Is there a direct proof?

Comment: Take Sierpinski's proof and apply it to this case by relativizing the general context to this specific context.

Comment: The proofs I know of Sierpinski's theorem use either the Alexandrov-Urysohn characterisation of the irrationals, or Brouwer's characterisation of the Cantor set and so are fairly non-constructive. It might be possible to peel away the abstract arguments for this specific case but I don't think it would be any more illuminating.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a direct proof. I’ll show first that $X=(0,1)\cap\Bbb Q$ is homeomorphic to $Y=[0,1)\cap\Bbb Q$.

Fix $\alpha\in(0,1)\setminus\Bbb Q$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $I_n=(\alpha^{n+1},\alpha^n)\cap\Bbb Q$; then $\{I_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a partition of $X$ into open intervals. (Note that for me $\Bbb N$ includes $0$.) Define a new linear order $\preceq$ on $Y$ as follows.

> Let $x,y\in Y$.
>
> 1. If $x,y\in I_n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, then $x\preceq y$ iff $x\le y$.
> 2. If $x\in I_{2m}$ and $y\in I_{2n}$ for distinct $m,n\in\Bbb N$, then $x\preceq y$ iff $m<n$.
> 3. If $x\in I_{2m+1}$ and $y\in I_{2n+1}$ for distinct $m,n\in\Bbb N$, then $x\preceq y$ iff $m>n$.
> 4. If $x\in I_{2m}$ and $y\in I_{2n+1}$ for some $m,n\in\Bbb N$, then $x\preceq y$.
> 5. If $x\in I_{2n}$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, then $x\preceq 0$.
> 6. If $x\in I_{2n+1}$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, then $0\preceq x$.

Schematically, $\preceq$ is the left-to-right order in the following diagram, where each $I_n$ retains its usual internal order:

$$I_0\quad I_2\quad I_4\quad\ldots\quad 0\quad\ldots\quad I_5\quad I_3\quad I_1$$

It’s not hard to verify that $\preceq$ is a dense linear order on $Y$ and that the associated order topology is just the usual topology on the set $Y$.

For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $\beta_n=\frac12(1-\alpha^n)$ and $\gamma_n=\frac12(1+\alpha^n)$, and let $J_{2n}=(\beta_n,\beta_{n+1})\cap\Bbb Q$ and $J_{2n+1}=(\gamma_{n+1},\gamma_n)\cap\Bbb Q$. Then $\{J_{2n}:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a partition of $\left(0,\frac12\right)\cap\Bbb Q$ into open intervals, $\{J_{2n+1}:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a partition of $\left(\frac12,1\right)\cap\Bbb Q$ into open intervals, and $X$ ‘looks like’ this as a linear order:

$$J_0\quad J_2\quad J_4\quad\ldots\quad\frac12\quad\ldots\quad J_5\quad J_3\quad J_1\;.$$

For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $f_n:I_n\to J_n$ be an order-isomorphism; it’s easy enough to write down an explicit formula for $f_n$ as a linear function, if one really wants to take the trouble. Finally, let $f=\left\{\left\langle 0,\frac12\right\rangle\right\}\cup\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}f_n$; i.e.,

$$f:Y\to X:y\mapsto\begin{cases}
f_n(y),&\text{if }y\in J_n\text{ for some }n\in\Bbb N\\
\frac12,&\text{if }y=0\;.
\end{cases}$$

It’s straightforward to verify that $f$ is a homeomorphism. (Note that if one knows the result that every countable dense linear order is order-isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$, the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic is immediate once one has the order $\preceq$.)

To complete the proof that $X$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$, just notice that $X$ is the disjoint union of the clopen sets $(0,\alpha)\cap\Bbb Q$ and $(\alpha,1)\cap\Bbb Q$, and $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$ is the disjoint union of the clopen sets $[0,\alpha)\cap\Bbb Q$ and $(\alpha,1]\cap\Bbb Q$. By what we’ve already proved, $(0,\alpha)\cap\Bbb Q$ is homeomorphic to $[0,\alpha)\cap\Bbb Q$, and $(\alpha,1)\cap\Bbb Q$ is homeomorphic to $(\alpha,1]\cap\Bbb Q$, so $X$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Very Clever. We missed you a lot Brian! Is everything OK? We have been worried about you all this time. We are glad you are back. Like someone said couple months ago in Meta, your not being here left a hole on many many users here. It felt so empty, so meaningless MSE without you. Dont leave again!

Comment: @Horacio: Thank you. I expect to be around, though probably not so active as before.